# How to get size of const array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, size

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int triTable[4][6] = {
    {},
    {0, 8, 3},
    {0, 1, 9},
    {1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1},
};

int main() {
  const int *f = triTable[3];
  int size = sizeof(f)/sizeof(*f);
  cout << size; 
}
```

This gives me wrong numbers. It should print **6**. How can I get it?

Comment: Since `f` is a pointer, `sizeof f` will be the size of the *pointer* and not what it might point to. Since you're programming in C++ there's a very easy solution: Use either `std::array` or `std::vector` instead, where you can easily get the number of elements.

Comment: `sizeof(f)/sizeof(*f)` is equal to `sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int)` which has no relationship to either dimension of `triTable`.    To get the first dimension (i.e. 4) you need to calculate `sizeof(triTable)/sizeof(*triTable)`.   To get the second dimension (i.e. 6) you need to calculate `sizeof(*triTable)/sizeof(**triTable)`.   You can't use `f` to get either, since the conversion of `triTable[3]` to `int *` loses the size information.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get size of const array in c++?

Like this:

```
std::size(triTable[3])
```

> This gives me wrong numbers.

You generally cannot get the size of an array by using a pointer to element of that array.

Comment: This not working correct. Change `triTable[3]` to triTable[1] what should return 3, but still returns max 6.

Comment: @trshmanx you're mistaken. The size of all inner arrays is the same: 6. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As stated `sizeof f` is the size of the pointer not the size of the object where it points to, as also said, using STL containers is a much better option given that they have size members that keep track of the size of the container.

That being said, if you're adamant in using a C style array, a solution would be to wrap it in a `struct` or `class` and return the size from there, ***i.e***:

```
struct myArray
{
    const int triTable[4][6] = {
        {},
        {0, 8, 3},
        {0, 1, 9},
        {1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1},
    };

    const int size = std::size(triTable[3]); // size data member

    int arraySize() const{
        return std::size(triTable[3]); // size method
    }

};

int main()
{
    myArray a;
    std::cout << a.size << "\n";
    std::cout << a.arraySize();
}
```

Output:

```
6
6
```

Comment: This not working correct. Change `triTable[3]` to triTable[1] what should return 3, but still returns max 6.

Comment: You declare `triTable[4][6]`, all the lines have 6 elements regardless of if they are initialized or not. That's how arrays work. In your initialization all the uninitialized members will be implicitly initialized to 0. https://godbolt.org/z/YaYz7hMYT